# How to get random element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I return a random element in jQuery by doing something like `$(.class).random.click()`?

So, if `.class` had 10 links, it would randomly click one of them.

Here is what I did:

```
var rand_num = Math.floor(Math.random()*$('.member_name_and_thumb_list a').size());
$(".member_name_and_thumb_list a").eq(rand_num).click();
```

Comment: you could grab all the elements with a regular jquery selector, $('.class'), then instead of iterating through them using .each, just grab a random one . or you could create an array of all the classes, then generate a random index (based on the range of the array). then go $('.randomclass').click().

Comment: since jQuery 1.8 we should use length instead of size.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
var n_elements = $(".someClass").length;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*n_elements);
$(".someClass").eq(random).click();
```

Comment: On chrome it pops out: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Round'` it is `var random = Math.round(Math.random()*10);`

Comment: Use Math.floor instead of Math.round for an even distribution. Using Math.round in this case will favour 1 to 8 over 0 and 9.

Comment: I recommend replacing `10` with `$(".someClass").length`. Otherwise, this will break if the number of links changes.

Answer (score 62):

You can write a custom filter ([taken from here](http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/2008/12/18/jquery-random-filter/)):

```
jQuery.jQueryRandom = 0;
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[":"], {
    random: function(a, i, m, r) {
        if (i == 0) {
            jQuery.jQueryRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length);
        };
        return i == jQuery.jQueryRandom;
    }
});
```

Example usage:

```
$('.class:random').click()
```

The same thing but as a plugin instead:

```
​jQuery.fn.random = function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);  
    return jQuery(this[randomIndex]);
};
```

Example usage:

```
$('.class').random().click()
```

Comment: gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` with jQuery 1.11.3

Answer (score 46):

If you don't want to hard code the number of elements to choose from, this works:

```
things = $('.class');
$(things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)]).click()
```

Comment: This is a great answer... efficient and standalone with nothing more than a single selector.

Comment: It's the second time I'm coming here. Why cant we upvote more?

Answer (score 10):

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

$('.class').eq(rand).click();
```

`Math.random()` gets you a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1, so multiplying it by 10 and rounding it down gets you 0 to 9. `.eq()` is 0 indexed, so this will get you a random jQuery element out of the 10 you have.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest doing it the jQuery way using `.eq()` and `.trigger()`.

```
$elements.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $elements.length)).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select random item by class name using jquery method `eq()`

see the example bellow.

```
var len = $(".class").length
var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ) + 1;
$(".class").eq(random).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

[randojs.com](https://randojs.com) makes this a simple one-liner:

```
rando($("a")).value[0].click()
```

The ".value" is there because you also have the option to get the index of the random jQuery element. The "[0]" is there to turn the jQuery element into a plain JavaScript element. If you add the following to the head of your html document, you can do pretty much whatever you want with randomness easily. Random values from arrays, random jquery elements, random properties from objects, and even preventing repetitions if needed.

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```