# Assign class through JQuery by selecting random ID

Tags: jquery

I have a range of divs, each with an incremental ID:

```
<div id="1">contents</div>
<div id="2">contents</div>
<div id="3">contents</div>
<div id="4">contents</div>
<div id="5">contents</div>
<div id="6">contents</div>
```

...

I'm trying to assign a class through JQuery by selecting by ID: `$('#id').addClass('someClass');` but I want the '#id' to be selected randomly from the range I have there. The range could be sizable, maybe up to 50 ids or more. I'm guessing this will have to read the IDs as number, right?
How do I get a random number there?

...Here's the full scheme:

```
setInterval ( "flipit()", 3000 );

function flipit ( ) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var elmId = 'nS_' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        $('#' + elmId).addClass('numSen2');
    });
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">

.numSen {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.numSen2 {
    visibility: visible;
}

</style>

<div class="numSen" id="nS_1">contents</div>
<div class="numSen" id="nS_2">contents</div>
<div class="numSen" id="nS_3">contents</div>
<div class="numSen" id="nS_4">contents</div>
<div class="numSen" id="nS_5">contents</div>
<div class="numSen" id="nS_6">contents</div>
```

Comment: Element IDs cannot start with a number.

Comment: @Interrobang Correct, though they can in html 5.

Comment: You also want to remove the class from the other elements, right?

Answer (score 1):

`'#id'` is just a string. So, after fixing your IDs (they must start with a letter), build a string like you would anywhere else:

```
var elmId = 'somePrefix_' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
$('#' + elmId).addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: Lovely, now perhaps I should've made my whole scheme clear from the get go... This approach works but now I also need to undo this through setInterval. What I'm going for is sort of like an on/off visibility switch for those divs. In other words I want a random div to show up, stay on for 3 seconds and then turn it off while another random div repeats this process and shows up. I'm editing my original post to show code...

Comment: @user1233337: Sounds like a _new_ problem. Please don't ruin all the answers by changing the question so fundamentally at this late stage.

Answer (score 1):

I would re-work your elements so they have some class ahead of time.  This way, you can select an element from those that you want to change, rather than everything.

```
<div class="addClasstoMe">contents</div>
<div class="addClasstoMe">contents</div>
<div class="addClasstoMe">contents</div>
<div class="addClasstoMe">contents</div>
<div class="addClasstoMe">contents</div>
<div class="addClasstoMe">contents</div>
```

And then in  your JavaScript:

```
var elements = $('.addClassToMe');
$(elements[Math.floor(Math.random()*elements.length)]).addClass('someClass');
```

Untested, but should work, or be close to it.

Comment: @Xander, Yeah, it was new to me too, and it turns out it's wrong, so I edited it back out.  I was checking to see if there was a jQuery way of doing it, but it looks like `:random` was a custom filter.  http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're now selecting six times as many elements as you were before, and doing so from the same pool of elements (the document).

Comment: Fixed... couldn't rollback for some reason, so re-wrote it again.

Comment: If you want to use the `:random` filter, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3614980/362536

Comment: This won't work.  `elements[...]` will return the element, not a jquery object.  You can't call `addClass` on it.  You want to use `eq()`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, Thanks for catching that.  This wasn't an issue in my first version, but while trying to rollback and rewrite, I left out the `$`.  Thanks.

Comment: I posted a shorter version that would work without the need to filter the array. Why the array anyway? Would it improve performance?

Comment: @Brad: Use `.eq()` rather than creating a whole new jQuery object.

Comment: Yeah, I think creating a new object and calculating the length at the same time could hurt performance.

Comment: Care to explain in more detail, or post an example?  There is nothing inefficient about using the `.length` property of an array, and I don't follow how `.eq()` applies here.

Comment: I think the rule _define `length` outside_ also applies for this. Think of a `for` loop. Although there's not much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.floor` in combination with `Math.random()` to create a random selector:

```
var selector = '#' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1);

$(selector).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even shorter. This will select a `div` with random `id` between 1-100 and `hide()` it:

```
$('div#'+~~(Math.random()*101)).hide();
```

**Edit:**

```
var $divs = $('div'), len = $divs.length;
$divs.filter('#'+~~(Math.random()*++len)).hide();
```

Comment: Your solution works by selecting elements which have pre-assigned IDs, assumes a specific number of them and no gap between ID numbers.  I don't believe this is a very good way to do this, as you'll need to be dynamically updating your JavaScript along with your page as you add/remove elements.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. You could use `filter()` too. See edit.

Comment: @Brad: The question heavily implies that this is fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Then up-vote it.  I didn't say that this solution doesn't work... elclanrs had asked why I was doing what I was doing rather than doing what he was doing, and I explained.

Comment: @Brad: I'll upvote when I want to. I'm just replying to your comment. I see now that you were replying to a question.. how confusing to do it in a different place!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I did because it was mostly relevant to his post.  Sorry for any confusion.