# javascript simple random game

Tags: javascript, html

im just starting out with javascript so go ez on me. i have an exercise where i have to create 4 divs that are a box's. and each time you refresh the page one div is the correct one to select. the main question im wondering is how can match a div to random number ?

my divs in the html are as follows

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

for javascript all i have so far is

```
var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);
```

but im not sure how i can make a function to say if `randomNumber == div#` ? then do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right so you have four divs as you explained.  We're going to want to add code to them that processes the user's clicks so we'll add what's called an *event handler* to them.

```
<div id="div1" onclick="process(1)"></div>
<div id="div2" onclick="process(2)"></div>
<div id="div3" onclick="process(3)"></div>
<div id="div4" onclick="process(4)"></div>
```

Now in a script tag **above** these divs in the code put the following function:

```
function ( divNum ) {
    // Define box as the div on which the user clicked
    var box = document.getElementById('div' + divNum);

    // Compare the div the user clicked on to the random number
    if ( divNum === randomNumber ) {
        // The user chose right
        box.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
    else {
        // The user chose incorrect
        box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('div' + randomNumber);
```

That should do it.  Then you can set all the properties on the element that you need from there.

---

If you need to do anything complicated, I would take a different approach, make the divs of a specific class to select from, and utilize jQuery.  This was asked last week, and you can find my answer that also applies to your specific question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9450352/362536

Comment: all i have to do if the user click the correct box then it will turn black, if not it will turn red.

Comment: @DrekPil, Ha, then you should have mentioned that in your question.  You only asked about "matching a div to a random number".

Comment: sorry i thought i could figure out the rest on my own but i was wrong :<