# How to create a jQuery selection which is a random sample of another jQuery selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question is similar to [How to get random element in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614944/how-to-get-random-element-in-jquery), except that instead of a single randomly selected element, I would like to get a subset of *k* distinct, randomly sampled elements (similar to Python's [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)).

For inputs which are arrays instead of jQuery objects, I came up with the following:

```
function randomSample(arr, k) {
    var arr = arr.slice();      // Work with a copy of the original array
    var samples = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        samples.push(arr.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0]);
    }
    return samples;
}
```

I would like to adapt this function to the case where the input is a jQuery object instead of an array. However, I'm struggling with this because I can't find a way to create an 'empty' jQuery object and 'push' elements to it.

What I'm doing now is altering the selected element (by adding a class `"yellow"` to it) and then re-running a jQuery selector with `not.(".yellow")` in order to sample without replacement. Here is a snippet (adapted from https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slice demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  button {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .yellow {
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><button>Turn slice yellow</button>
  <span>Click the button!</span></p>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

<script>
function colorEm(k) {
  var $div = $("div");
  $div.removeClass("yellow");

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    var $notYetHighlighted = $("div").not(".yellow");
    var start = Math.floor(Math.random() * $notYetHighlighted.length);
    var end = start + 1;
    if (end === $notYetHighlighted.length) {
      end = undefined;
    }
    if (end) {
      $notYetHighlighted.slice(start, end).addClass("yellow");
    } else {
      $notYetHighlighted.slice(start).addClass("yellow");
    }
  }
}

$( "button" ).click( function() { colorEm(3) } );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this 'modifying and re-querying' paradigm the only way to randomly sample a jQuery object?

Answer (score 1):

i rewrite your script to jquery function. I think it's easy to change it later.

```
/**
 * MyFunction to highliting div
 */
$.fn.myFunctionName = function(e) {
  let num = e.data.num;
  let bgCss = "yellow";
  let elements = $('div');
      elements.removeClass(bgCss); // remove highlight class from all divs


  function doHighlite() {
    let randomSquere = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length); // get random element index

    // add class if not exist or try generate next element
    if(!$(elements[randomSquere]).hasClass(bgCss)) {
        $(elements[randomSquere]).addClass(bgCss);
    }
    else {
      doHighlite();
    }
  };

  // highlight desired number of elements
  for(let i=0; i<num;i++) {
    doHighlite();
  }
}
```

And you can run it with parameter num

```
$(".red").on('click', { num: 5 }, $.fn.myFunctionName);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m1rtcpdv/)